# Visual bug when using Swipe Refresh Layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I use Swipe Refresh Layout in my Recycler view. When user pull swipe refresh enough and circle appeared and push back without calling onRefresh function small peace of the circle remain see the photo. [image]
I use transperent app bar but problem in something other cause even without it problem exsists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved by seting swipeRefreshLayout.setProgressViewOffset(false,0,50);

> public void setProgressViewOffset (boolean scale, int start, int end)
>
> The refresh indicator starting and resting position is always
>   positioned near the top of the refreshing content. This position is a
>   consistent location, but can be adjusted in either direction based on
>   whether or not there is a toolbar or actionbar present.
>
> Parameters
>
> scale Set to true if there is no view at a higher z-order than where
>   the progress spinner is set to appear.
>
> start The offset in pixels from the top of this view at which the
>   progress spinner should appear.
>
> end The offset in pixels from the top of this view at which the
>   progress spinner should come to rest after a successful swipe gesture.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `setRefreshing(false)` inside the OnRefreshListener?

Comment: Yeah, I have that function. There are two scenarios here: 1.User pull not enough to call this function and pull back(onRefresh() function did'n call) to hide it. 2.Pull enough to call it (starts circling until setRefreshing(false) is called) . My bug is appeared when first scenario is occurred.